# QBoxLayout with QMainWindow vs QWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I'd like to ask about the thing that is happening ,when I use QHBoxLayout with QMainWindow and with QWidget.I'm trying to change window title style, by connecting 2 widgets.
This what's happening:
Under QWidget
[image]

This is the code for this:
TitleBar.h

```
#ifndef MYTITLEBAR_H
#define MYTITLEBAR_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPixmap>

class MyTitleBar : public QWidget
{
public:
    MyTitleBar( QWidget* parent );
public slots:
    void showSmall();
    void showMaxRestore();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* me );
    void mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent* me );

private:
    QToolButton* minimize;
    QToolButton* maximize;
    QToolButton* close;
    QToolButton* custom;
    QPixmap restorePix, maxPix, closePix, minPix, customPix;
    bool maxNormal;
    QPoint startPos;
    QPoint clickPos;
};

#endif // MYTITLEBAR_H
```

TitleBar.cpp

```
#include "mytitlebar.h"

MyTitleBar::MyTitleBar( QWidget* parent )
{
    this->setWindowFlags( Qt::FramelessWindowHint );

    minimize = new QToolButton(this);
    maximize = new QToolButton(this);
    close = new QToolButton(this);
    custom = new QToolButton(this);

    closePix.load( "close.png" );
    close->setIcon( closePix );

    maxPix.load( "maximize.png" );
    maximize->setIcon( maxPix );

    minPix.load( "minimize.png" );
    minimize->setIcon( minPix );

    customPix.load( "custom_icon.png" );
    custom->setIcon( customPix );

    QLabel* label = new QLabel(this);
    label->setText( "Custom Window" );

    QHBoxLayout* HBox = new QHBoxLayout( this );

    HBox->addWidget( custom );
    HBox->addWidget( label );
    HBox->addWidget( minimize );
    HBox->addWidget( maximize );
    HBox->addWidget( close );



}

void MyTitleBar::showSmall()
{

}

void MyTitleBar::showMaxRestore()
{

}

void MyTitleBar::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *me)
{

}

void MyTitleBar::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *me)
{

}
```

Under QMainWindow:
[image]

The code is exactly the same as for QWidget, but I've changed the parent and inheritance to QMainWindow.And returning to the question why is this happening and how I can fix this? In the main window it's just intancing the class and move it to the right place, that it'd look like a window title bar and is the same as for QWidget and QMainWindow.
I need to use QMainWindow as parent, because the main window is inheritance of QMainWindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that QMainWindow already has a layout, see the documentation [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details), so the code won't work the same way as for a QWidget, you need to use the [centralWidget](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget), set a layout to `centralWidget` and add all your widgets to the layout.

Comment: Thx for answering, just a btw question , if I get many classes that are inherited from QGraphicsItem and implement them mousePressEvent(..), will this method react to any presses or presses to this item ?

Comment: I don't know that, logically it would get presses on the item only, but you should check the documentation and if that is not clear, make a small test project and if you still have doubts ask another question (if you continue here guys that had used QGraphicsItem and know the answer might skip this question and comments)

Comment: Ok :) , I already ask too many questions at the same time, makes me a bit sad.